# Show biasedness of estimator of discrete uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, uniform-distribution, parameter-estimation

Let be $X:\Omega\to[0,1,2,3,\dots, \theta]$ a **discrete** random variable which obeys a uniform distribution. We don't know $\theta$ and estimate it by the maximum of the sample $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$, denoted by $T(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Show that the estimator is biased.

My approach is quite simple:

\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}(T(x_1,\dots,x_n))\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\theta}P(T(x_1,\dots,x_n)=k)\cdot k<\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\theta}P(T(x_1,\dots,x_n)=k)\cdot \theta\\
&=\theta\cdot\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\theta}P(T(x_1,\dots,x_n)=k)=\theta,
\end{align*}
which shows $\mathbb{E}(T(x_1,\dots,x_n))<\theta$. On the last equal sign I have used the fact that all probabilities sum up to $1$. I got zero points for that solution and am wondering what is wrong with that approach?

Comment: This seems correct to me. Did you ask for feedback?

Comment: @VincentBatens, I have not yet received an answer from my tutor. Maybe she is wrong with her assessment.

Comment: It could be that she wanted more details. For example, the fact that you can have a strict inequality is because there is at least one $P(T(x_1, \dots, x_n) = k)$ which is nonzero for a $k \geq 1$ (all of them are but one suffices). Maybe she thought it was incorrect for you to keep the sample $x_1, \dots, x_n$ and wanted you to properly introduce a random variable $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$, of which $x_1, \dots, x_n$ would be a $(X_1, \dots, X_n)(\omega)$. Or as you said maybe she's wrong, but you got to have some faith in your tutor. Zero points is very harsh though, I agree.